# What do the different vault levels reward you with in Legends of Runeterra?

Tags: legends-of-runeterra

In Legends of Runeterra you get unlocks every Tuesday thanks to the Weekly Vault. What are the rewards for the various levels?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Official Legends of Runeterra website features [This Page](https://playruneterra.com/en-us/news/progression-by-the-numbers) on how to progress in the game (rewards, loot, etc.). The Vault section contains the following image, detailing the rewards and XP needed for each level:

[image]

---

To clarify, in order of first appearance (top to bottom), those are Bronze, Silver, Gold, Platinum and Diamond Chests. There's also Champion Wildcards to be gained (Orange Wildcards).

Each Chest contains rewards ranging from Capsules (that contain assorted Wildcards) and Shards.

[image]

Comment: Also for every level above the Max you get an extra capsule as well. With the limit being unknown at this time.( But supposedly 99 extra capsules)